# YORK AC unit rusted support arm

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

[image]I have an old YORK ac unit still running R22 and have recently cleaned the entire unit inside and out. As I took apart the unit, one of the 4 corner supporting outside vents was rusted completely and basically fell off when I was sweeping around the unit....bottom of unit is all rusted and replacement with a new corner piece probably wouldn't work.... what are some diy ideas to remedy?

I have the unit back together and all seems good with only 3 sides supporting the fan and top piece. Has anyone dealt with this before?

TIA

[image: AC unit with out supporting corner]

Comment: Pictures, please. It's really hard to speculate about solutions that might work with only a verbal decription of this sort of problem. Click the "edit" just below your post and then use the little picture of mountains to upload a picture (or if the site win't let you due to reputation you don't have yet, upload your picture to imgur, copy the link for it, and edit THAT in, and someone will come along and get the picture in for you.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you'd be alright the way it is. An easy fix would be to go to your home store and find the rack where they have pieces of steel in various lengths and pick up a piece 1/8" by 1" by 36" or whatever size is appropriate for your unit. Attach it underneath that top corner lip and wedge it into the concrete by the bottom lip. The bottom lip looks pretty corroded so no sense in trying to attach it there but a tight fit against the concrete should hold it firm. Spray it with some Rust-oleum that's a close match and you're good to go.

Comment: Or cut it a little bit longer, angle it out a little bit, bend the bottom to suit, and drill a hole to bolt it into the concrete pad. If you can buy galvanized, the paint has less work to do, rust-wise.